# There exists a point with a bigger distance from a point than a compact

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a Banach space and fix a convex compact set $K\subseteq X$ with $0\notin K$.

Is it true that there exists $x \in X$ such that
$
\|x\|>\max_{k \in K} \|x-k\|?
$

---

The answer is positive in the case $X=\mathbf{R}^k$ (and, more generally, in Hilbert spaces): draw a "suitable" line passing through the origin which intersects $K$ and choose a point $x$ which is sufficiently far away from $0$, on the side of $K$ (see details below).

What about the general case in Banach spaces? (A previous version of the question was in the context of locally convex topological vector spaces with a compatible translation-invariant metric; cf. comments of user8268.)

Comment: is $d$ supposed to be translation-invariant?

Comment: There exists a compatible metric $d$ which is translation-invariant provided that $X$ is first countable: if needed, assume it

Comment: it's just that without that assumption it is not true, even for $X=\Bbb R$ (and a suitable $d$)

Comment: Ok, I added the hypothesis, now wlog $x=0$

Comment: how about $X=\Bbb R$, $d(x,y)=min(|x-y|,1)$, $x=0$, $K=[1,2]$?

Comment: @user8268 you are right, thank you. I rephrased the whole question.

Comment: Can you give a proof for $\mathbb{R}^k$? The sketch given in your question does not work, at least not for an arbitrary line intersecting $K$. Consider $K = \{ 1 \} \times [-1,1] \subset X =  \mathbb{R}^2$. The line through $p = (1,1)$ does not have the desired property. For any $x = tp$ with $t \ge 1$ we get $\lVert x \rVert_2 =t \sqrt{2}$ but $\lVert x - (-1,1) \rVert_2 > \lVert x \rVert_2$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Indeed it was just a sketch. Let $H$ be a $n-1$-dimensional hyperplane separating $0$ and $K$ (this is clearly geometrically; formally, use the Hahn-Banach theorem). Draw *the* line $L$ passing through $0$ and perpendicular to $H$. The projection of $K$ on $H$ is bounded, hence contained in a $n-1$ dimensional open ball $B$ with center $L \cap H$. Draw a $n$-dimensional open ball passing through $B$ with center $x$ on $L$ sufficiently far from $0$, and you're done (since it contains $K$ and not $0$).

Comment: I see. In my counterexample I was aware that the line through $p = (1,0)$ will do which fits to your proof (BTW: I hace a typo in my comment. It should be $\lVert x - (1,-1) \rVert_2$). It seems that is essential to work with a inner product space to define "perpendicular".

Comment: Well, it is essential just we want to replicate the above proof as it is: in a Hilbert space, let $H$ be the separating (closed) hyperplane, then there exists the unique point $y\in H$ which is nearest to $0$ (here we need completeness). $K$ is compact hence bounded, hence the projection of $K$ on $H$ is contained in a ball $B$ with center $y$. Now it is easy to show that there exists a ball with center $\alpha y$ passing through $B$, containing $K$ and not containing $0$. What about the case of Banach spaces (without the notion of orthogonality)?